# WiFi cuts out while bluetooth is in use

Tags: networking, bluetooth, hardware

Recently, I've gotten into using my Bluetooth headset to listen to music while I work. I've noticed that while listening to music over Bluetooth that the WiFi connection fails.

I've connected my headset and started playing music. To test my theory, I pinged google from the terminal before, during and after the headset is connected. Before and after it's connected, I got a 0% packet loss. While connected, I've gotten up to a 79% packet loss.

I've noticed that when I press the physical key that disables my wireless radio that WiFi and Bluetooth are turned off. This is normal as it happens in Ubuntu and Windows 7. I guess they're in the same chip?

I'd like to try to use Bluetooth and WiFi simultaneously, but I can't find a solution.

System Specs:
Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS, 64-bit
11.6 GB RAM
Some sort of Intel wireless chip, I don't know the name. (Uses the WiMax board)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i remember well bluetooth uses the same frequencies that wifi 2.4 ghz uses. When i use my bluetooth speakers attached to my tablet while watching videos the videos an my tablet sometimes stutter because the wifi of my tablet interferes with my bluetooth speakers. i hope for you to find a solution, i dont have any.

Comment: Every peripheral I use with it uses the 2.4 GHz band. Nothing interferes with anything except the headset...